# List closing up and showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is, whenever the user views one sub-category, and then chooses to view another one, I would like to slideUp the current visible sub-category and slideDown the new sub-category that the user wants to see.

#### HTML

```
<ul class="depth-one">
    <li>Category 1
        <ul class="depth-two">
            <li>Category 1.1</li>
            <li>Category 1.2</li>
            <li>Category 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 2
        <ul class="depth-two">
            <li>Category 2.1</li>
            <li>Category 2.2</li>
            <li>Category 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 3
        <ul class="depth-two">
            <li>Category 3.1</li>
            <li>Category 3.2</li>
            <li>Category 3.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.depth-one {
    display:block;
}
.depth-two {
    display:none;
}
```

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".depth-one > li").click(function (e) {
        if (e.currentTarget == e.target) {
            selector = $(this).find(' > .depth-two');
            if ($(selector).css("display") == "none") {
                $('.depth-one > ul').slideUp(400);
                $(selector).slideDown(800);
            } else {
                selector.slideUp(800);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NB4bN/5/)

Comment: you can try with `http://jqueryui.com/accordion/` plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your click function:  `$('.depth-one > li > ul').slideUp(800);`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PxhLV/)**

Whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".depth-one > li").click(function (e) {
        $('.depth-one > li > ul').slideUp(800);
        if (e.currentTarget == e.target) {
            selector = $(this).find(' > .depth-two');
            if ($(selector).css("display") == "none") {
                $('.depth-one > ul').slideUp(400);
                $(selector).slideDown(800);
            } else {
                selector.slideUp(800);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding one line (`$('.depth-two').not(this).slideUp(800);`) to my answer to your last question, you get the results you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".depth-one > li").click(function () {
        $('.depth-two').not(this).slideUp(800);
        selector = $(this).find(' > .depth-two');
        if ($(selector).css("display") == "none") {
            selector.slideDown(800);
        } else {
            selector.slideUp(800);
        }
    });
    $('li li').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NB4bN/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

This might be all the code you need:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".depth-one > li").click(function (e) {
          $(".depth-one > li > .depth-two").slideUp(800);
          $(this).find(' > .depth-two').slideDown(800);
     });
 });
```

Comment: If you click a sub li, the same menu will slide up and then back down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".depth-one > li").click(function (e) {
        $("ul.toggled").slideToggle().removeClass('toggled');
        $('ul', this).slideToggle().addClass('toggled');        
    });

});
```

Comment: If you click a sub li, the same menu will slide up and then back down